# Creating custom tabularx

Tags: macros, horizontal-alignment, environments, tabularx

I am trying to create a new environment in order to change the layout for tabularx, since the original is not looking like it should. I want the picture to be on the right side wrapped by the text. My idea was to create a new environment with new commands inside to align everything as I want, maybe someone has some tips for me how to do this, and how to structure everything? Thanks in advance...
My code is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}  %Quotes won't work without babel
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   %This is very important!
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}, breaklinks=true, pdftex=true, raiselinks=true]{hyperref}
%\usepackage{tabularx}
\RequirePackage{mypackage}

%\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedright}X}

\begin{document}
\section{Description}
\begin{tabularx}%{\linewidth}{|Y|Y|}\hline

\multicolumn{}{}{some text}
\begin{itemize}
\item  Fixing
\item  Remastering
\item  Converting
\item  Control
\end{itemize}
% & 
\begin{center} \resizebox{10cm}{!}{\includegraphics{picture.png}}\\
\textit{picturedescription}\end{center}
%\tabularnewline \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

At the moment it is working like this, but i want to get it working without commenting anything out, or in case change some commands into my own. In addition my custom package looks like this, I want to do all the layouting there:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{mypackage}[2012/11/20]

\newenvironment{tabularx}{%
    \begin{center}
    \end{center}
}

    \renewcommand{\multicolumn}{}
\endinput
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{>{\raggedleft}p{#1}}
```

for the redefinition of the X column. if you want it flush right. And by the way: there is not need for a `\resizebox`. Use `\includegraphics[width=10cm]{picture.png}`

Comment: I forgot to tell that everything except for mypackage.sty is generated automatically, i have no influence on this, for this reason i want to modify it with my own package. Thanks for the fast response, but i am not really sure where exactly to put this line:
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{>{\raggedleft}p{#1}}
maybe you could tell me

Comment: into your preamble after loading `mypackage`